# open an attached pdf on click of a part in 3d model... Acrobat javascript

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I want to open an attached pdf when I click on a part of 3d model. When I try

```
host.exportDataObject({ cName: "MindSphere_GettingStarted.pdf", nLaunch: 2 });
```

it throws an error

```
TypeError: Invalid argument type.
Doc.exportDataObject:0:Doc undefined:Exec
===> Parameter cName.Line:
```

Answer (score 0):

Object don't pass well across the 3D JavaScript engine and the host. Try this instead

```
host.exportDataObject("MindSphere_GettingStarted.pdf", null, false, 2);
```